# banding issue on wall

Tags: shaders, lighting

[image]

I'm experiencing very ugly banding on a wall. The scene is lit with spot lamps and geometry lights (with hdr softbox textures). The wall itself is perfectly flat, but has a beveled 90° angle right above the floor. I tried to add subdivisions and support loops, that made the problem less visible, but didn't eliminate it completely. The displacement has no influence on the issue.

If I hide the geo lights (softboxes) and replace them with area lamps, no banding is visible. Unfortunately I really (really!) need those softboxes, because I have a highly reflective object in the scene, that has to catch nice and realistic reflections.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for your time.

The softbox:
[image]

## Edit

I couldn't reproduce the effect in a small test scene, so the problem might not even be related to the geo lights.

Comment: Would it be possible to upload your `.blend` file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and share the link in the question? It might help those who try to identify the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I panicked too early. When I stripped down the file to upload it here, I saw that I had two ground planes ontop of eachother. One of them was invisible for camera view, but was considered for glossy and diffuse bounces. This produced the banding artifacts.